# How to copy filename as text from a folder in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I am looking to copy the filename as text from a folder as seen in windows explorer in windows 7, so that i can paste in other editor.

I there any way to achieve this. I don't see any such feature in the context menu.

Note: I am looking for a windows solution, i don't want/can't install new software.

Comment: One single filename, or the entire folder's contents as a list? If you only want a single filename then you can click a file once -> press `F2` -> highlight the entire filename -> `Ctrl` + `C` -> paste the filename into your other editor.

Comment: what chris mentionsi s the rename option. It can take some skill if you are trying to left click. F2 is fine, another way, is right click the file and choose "rename" then just copy/paste the text there. Then hit ESC(escape).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+right-click > Copy as path

Yes that's not just the filename but often the full path's exactly what you want, else it's easily edited. This also works for multiple files by the way.

Comment: Ooo, very nice! Learn something new every day!

Comment: @BigChris if you didn't know about that, and you learn one thing a day, then you should try to learn more than one thing a day.

Comment: @barlop: Come on, everyone has to start somewhere, right? Stuff that's obvious to someone might be a revelation to others.

Comment: @Karan it's a joke, there are always little details of windows that for one reason or another somebody might not have run into.  (though copying a file's path seems like a strange one to not run into i.e. to not have googled at some point). But it's not a question of starting somewhere, it doesn't mean he's at a basic level. Just a little silly windows thing he wasn't aware of for some reason.

Comment: @barlop: Ah, that's ok then. I thought you were taking an uncalled for dig at him. All's well that ends well. :)

Comment: Do you remember what the website for windows xp tips was? by somebody called Karen(your name with an 'e').. it had a table of tips and registry tweaks.  She was an MVP

Comment: @barlop: Do you mean [Karen's Koncepts](http://koncepts.50webs.com/win.htm)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23011/discussion-between-barlop-and-karan).